# A problem with probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three cards are drawn from a deck of 52 poker cards.
I have to determine **the probability that there is at least one ace amongst the 3 drawn cards.**
The solution in the book is $\frac{4*\binom{51}{2}}{\binom{52}{3}} $ and I agree with that but my first attempt was
$\frac{\binom{4}{1}*\binom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{2}*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}} $.

If I compare the right number of combinations $4*\binom{51}{2}=5100 $ with the wrong one $\binom{4}{1}*\binom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{2}*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}=4808$ I realize that I'm forgetting something...

Then I have determine **the probability that at least two cards have the same value.**
Now I used
 $\frac{\binom{4}{2}*13*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}*13}{\binom{52}{3}}= \frac{73}{425} $ and it was correct.
Apparently I could use 
 $\binom{4}{2}*13*\binom{50}{1}= 3900 $  but the number of combinations are larger than $\binom{4}{2}*13*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}*13=3796$

Comment: With problems like this, it's often easier to work it backwards.  That is, compute the probability that your three doesn't have an ace.

Comment: @lulu yes, I did and the result is $73/425$

Comment: What is that meant to be?  The probability that you have no ace is $\binom {48}3/\binom {52}3 = \frac {4324}{5525}\approx .783$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Three cards are drawn from a deck of 52 poker cards.
>   I have to determine **the probability that there is at least one ace amongst the 3 drawn cards.**
>   The solution in the book is $\frac{4*\binom{51}{2}}{\binom{52}{3}} $ and I agree with that but my first attempt was
>   $\frac{\binom{4}{1}*\binom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{2}*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}} $.

Do not agree with the book.   The book's solution is wrong, and you were correct.

${4\binom{51}2}/{\binom{52}3}$ over counts cases where two or more aces are selected.   You had correctly considered this and counted them properly.

To verify, note that the probability for selecting no aces is $\binom{48}3/\binom{52}3$.   Adding this to the correct answer for the above will yield $1$; because you *certainly* draw either no ace or at least one ace.   It does so when added to your answer (revision: Binomial Theorem).   It does not yield $1$ when added to the book's answer.

> Then I have determine **the probability that at least two cards have the same value.** Now I used
>    $\frac{\binom{4}{2}*13*\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{3}*13}{\binom{52}{3}}= \frac{73}{425} $ and it was correct.

Indeed.   That is the probability for selecting a pair-&-single or a triple, and may also be written: $(\binom {13}{1}\binom 42\binom{12}1\binom 41+\binom {13}1\binom 43)/\binom{52}3$ .

And again, the probability for selecting three distinct kinds is: $\binom{13}{3}\binom 41^3/\binom {52}3$, which can be shown to yield $1$ when added to your answer.

You have used here the exact same logic as you used above.   Why would you think it was correct to do so here and not there?

Answer (score 2):

Probability of getting atleast one ace = 1 - probability of getting no ace 
$$= 1-\frac{48}{52}\cdot \frac{47}{51}\cdot \frac{46}{50}$$

Comment: I would have done the same like you, but the result for the first point is $3/13$ and it is already in my post

Comment: @Anne Your answer is correct.  The answer in the textbook is wrong.